# How to perform correlation between time-series of unequal frequencies

Tags: r, time-series

I measured room temperature every minute for 36 minutes and skin temperature 32 times per second for the same time period. I have 35 repeats of the experiment labelled (ID). I need to be able to look at the correlation but, the samples are of unequal sizes.

**Data:**

I have a data.frame `df1` with room temperature measured every minute and another  data.frame `df2` with skin temperature measured 32 times per second. I have 36 minutes worth of data. In addition there is another column called ID which shows the experiment number (1-35) but I don't know how to represent this in the following example data. So technically I'm looking for correlation for each SkinTemp vs RoomTemp based on ID.

```
    df1 <- data.frame(
        roomTemp = rnorm(1*36),
    )

   df2 <- data.frame(
        skinTemp = rnorm(32*60*36),
        )
```

I tried doing:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Y=c(df1,df2),
  Variable =factor(rep(c("RoomTemp", "SkinTemp"), times=c(length(df1), length(df2))))
)

cor(Data$Y~Data$Variable)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A rolling join or interpolation might be helpful for imputing `roomTemp` for times when `skinTemp` was measured. Below are examples of both. The first section is an update to deal with multiple IDs, followed by the original answer for the case of a single ID.

#### Modification for multiple IDs

This update addresses the case of data with multiple IDs where we want to either interpolate or do a rolling join separately for each ID.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size=16))
```

First, we'll create fake autocorrelated data for two separate IDs:

```
set.seed(395)
df1 <- data.frame(roomTemp = c(cumsum(rnorm(1*36)), cumsum(rnorm(1*36))),
                  ID = rep(c("A","B"), each=36))
df2 <- data.frame(skinTemp = c(cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01)),
                               cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01))),
                  ID = rep(c("A","B"), each=32*60*36))
```

Now we add a time column, but in this case I've also added a shift in `df1`, so that no `df1` measurement happens at the same time as a `df2` measurement, just to make the answer more general.

```
# Add time column
df1$time = rep(0:(0.5*nrow(df1)-1)*60 + 0.0438,2)
df2$time = rep(0:(0.5*nrow(df2)-1)/32, 2)
```

Convert the data frames to data tables. This time, we make `ID` a key column in addition to `time` so that the rolling join will occur separately for each `ID`.

```
# Convert data frames to data tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# Make ID and time key columns in both data frames (for joining)
setkey(df1, ID, time)
setkey(df2, ID, time)

# Rolling join roomTemp to nearest time value of skinTemp
df2 = df1[df2, roll="nearest"]

# Rename rolling joined room temperature column
names(df2)[grep("roomTemp", names(df2))] = "roomTempRoll"
```

To add the interpolated `roomTemp` by `ID`, I've used `map_df` from the `purrr` package. `map_df` operates separately on each `ID`. `approx` takes care of the interpolation. In the original answer I used `approxfun` to create an approximation function first, but here I've just done the interpolation directly in a single step. `map_df` returns a data frame, but we just need the `y` column, which has the interpolated values of `roomTemp`, so I've extracted those at the end of the `dplyr` function chain and assigned them to `roomTempInterp` in `df2`.

```
# Add interpolated room temperature by ID
df2$roomTempInterp = unique(df2$ID) %>% 
  map_df(~ approx(df1$time[df1$ID==.x], df1$roomTemp[df1$ID==.x], 
                  xout=df2$time[df2$ID==.x]), .id="ID") %>% .$y
```

In the plot below, we facet by `ID` so that we can see the imputed temperature values separately for each `ID`.

```
# Plot so we can see what the rolling joined room temperature and 
#  interpolated room temperature look like
ggplot(melt(df2, id.var=c("ID", "time")), aes(time, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(size=0.7) +
  geom_point(data=df1, aes(time, roomTemp), colour="black") +
  facet_grid(ID ~ .)
```

[image]

Here's one way to get the correlations by `ID`:

```
df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(r_interp = cor(skinTemp, roomTempInterp, use="pairwise.complete.obs"),
            r_roll = cor(skinTemp, roomTempRoll, use="pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

> ```
>       ID    r_interp      r_roll
> 1      A -0.04853998 -0.02993207
> 2      B -0.53993960 -0.53092150
> ```

#### Original Answer

First, I modified the sample data frames to add some autocorrelation, since that seemed a bit closer to your real experiment and makes visualization easier.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size=16))

# Fake data with autocorrelation
set.seed(395)
df1 <- data.frame(roomTemp = cumsum(rnorm(1*36)))
df2 <- data.frame(skinTemp = cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01)))
```

Now add a time column. You can work with actual datetime columns, but here I've just gone with numeric columns denominated in seconds.

```
# Add time column
df1$time = 0:(nrow(df1)-1)*60
df2$time = 0:(nrow(df2)-1)/32
```

For interpolation, we need a function that will interpolate room temperatures at the times when skin temperature is measured in between the room temperature measurements. `approxfun` performs linear interpolation between points. You can also use `splinefun` in a similar way to interpolate using splines.

```
# Function to interpolate room temperature between measurements
roomTempInterp = approxfun(df1$time, df1$roomTemp)
```

Convert the data frames to data tables in order to use `data.table`'s rolling join functionality.

```
# Convert data frames to data tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# Make time a key column in both data frames (for joining)
setkey(df1, time)
setkey(df2, time)
```

Now perform a rolling join to the nearest time value.

```
# Rolling join roomTemp to nearest time value of skinTemp
df2 = df1[df2, roll="nearest"]

# Rename rolling joined room temperature column
names(df2)[grep("roomTemp", names(df2))] = "roomTempRoll"
```

Merge original `roomTemp` measurements from `df1` into `df2`.

```
df2 = df1[df2, ]  # Equivalent to dplyr: df2 = left_join(df2, df1)
```

Add the interpolated room temperature using the function we created above.

```
# Add interpolated room temperature
df2$roomTempInterp = roomTempInterp(df2$time)
```

The interpolation method seems more realistic to me, especially if we can assume `roomTemp` changes relatively smoothly and monotonically between measurements. Below are the first 10 rows of `df2`, which includes the original `df2` data plus the new `roomTempRoll` and `roomTempInterp` columns and the original `roomTemp` measurements from `df1`. You can now use this data frame to assess correlation and other relationships between `roomTemp` and `skinTemp`.

> ```
>     roomTemp    time roomTempRoll     skinTemp roomTempInterp
>  1: -1.21529 0.00000     -1.21529 -0.006511475      -1.215290
>  2:       NA 0.03125     -1.21529 -0.014058076      -1.215531
>  3:       NA 0.06250     -1.21529 -0.017741690      -1.215773
>  4:       NA 0.09375     -1.21529 -0.030211177      -1.216014
>  5:       NA 0.12500     -1.21529 -0.027105225      -1.216255
>  6:       NA 0.15625     -1.21529 -0.035784295      -1.216497
>  7:       NA 0.18750     -1.21529 -0.031319748      -1.216738
>  8:       NA 0.21875     -1.21529 -0.033758959      -1.216979
>  9:       NA 0.25000     -1.21529 -0.040667384      -1.217220
> 10:       NA 0.28125     -1.21529 -0.026291442      -1.217462
> ```

Below is a plot so you can see what the rolling join and interpolated values look like. The black dots mark the original `roomTemp` measurements.

```
ggplot(melt(df2 %>% select(-roomTemp), id.var="time"), aes(time, value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(time, roomTemp), colour="black")
```

[image]

Comment: 1/2 This is an amazing answer, thank you very much! I think it does exactly what I'm after. There's one small difference: I have time-series for each of my patients/subjects/participants tagged onto the bottom of the previous patient's data. I imported the data like this and  added an ID column by means of lapply: l2 = bind_rows(lapply(l,  function(i) {temp <- read.table(i, header = FALSE,skip=14, nrow = 
        length(readLines(i)) - 16); setNames(temp, c("Time","SkinTemp","HeartRate","RespirationRate"))}), .id = "id")

Comment: 2/2 where l is a list of text files in my folder. So ID goes from 1 to 35. How would I apply your answer to each one of the participant's data but maintaining their ID AND keeping it in a format that ggplot would use? If you could shed some light on this, that would be fantastic! :-)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, it's made everything so much clearer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Below, I've provided a minimal example of how you might accomplish this correlation.

You can check out my comments below, but effectively what I've done is create bins (or "buckets") for each observation time of room temperature. Then, I roll up the skin temperature observations (which outnumber room temperature observations greatly) by those corresponding bins. So, since you get one *room* temperature observation for every 36*60*32 *skin* temperature observations, the first 36*60*32 skin temperature observations are rolled into bin '1'. The process continues from there, with the skin temperature observations from [36*60*32, 36*60*32*2] being rolled up into bin "2", and so on.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# create the times of our observations
time.room.temp <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct('02/20/2017', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), to = as.POSIXct('02/21/2017', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), by = 36*60)
time.skin.temp <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct('02/20/2017', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), to = as.POSIXct('02/21/2017', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), by = 1/32)

n.obs.room.temp <- length(room.temp)
n.obs.skin.temp <- length(skin.temp)

# create some "actual" temperature data
obs.room.temp <- rnorm(n.obs.room.temp, mean = 60, sd = 10)
obs.skin.temp <- rnorm(n.obs.skin.temp, mean = 95, sd = 5)

room.temp.df <- data.frame('room temp' = obs.room.temp, 'time' = time.room.temp)
skin.temp.df <- data.frame('skin temp' = obs.skin.temp, 'time' = time.skin.temp)

# Every 32 indices, seconds is incremented by one.. So our modulus calculuation should be every
# time the index evenly divides 36*60*32... there are 69120 skin-temp observations for every room-temp observation
# So we can effectively "bin" the different seconds for which we observed skin temperatures in order to create a mean temperature by bin,
# i.e. a mean skin temperature for every time at which room temp was recorded
bins <- cut(1:n.obs.skin.temp, seq(0, n.obs.skin.temp, 36*60*32), labels = 1:40)
skin.temp.df$bins <- bins

# Now, we can effectively group skin temperature observations by room temperature observations, and get the average (or median, if you like)
# temperature for each bin
shorter.skin.temp.df <- skin.temp.df %>%
  group_by(bins) %>%
  summarise(average.skin.temp = mean(skin.temp))

# Now we can get the correlation between the two types of temperatures!
cor(room.temp.df$room.temp, shorter.skin.temp.df$average.skin.temp)
```

Edit: a little bit of validation of the number of unique room temperature and "rolled-up" skin temperature observations:

```
> print(length(unique(skin.temp.df$bins)))
[1] 41
> print(length(unique(room.temp.df$time)))
[1] 41
```

So, you can rest easy knowing that there is a corresponding unique skin-temp observation time bin for each unique room temperature observation time.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you. I've found that I have unequal numbers of skin and room measurements for each experiment. I.e. the thermometer wasn't turned off at the same time during each experiment. So I added a column called ID for both skin and room temperatures which relates them to each experiment. Is there a way of binning the observations based on ID?

Comment: IIUC, you've already got "bins" for ID for your data. You probably could extend that `group_by` above to something like `group_by(ID, bins)`... But you'd want to ensure that the `bins` for each `ID` correspond to the correct time intervals. For example, for `ID = 1`, you might have time interval bins [[*t0*, *t1*), [*t1*, *t2*), ...]], while for `ID = 2` you might have [[*t1*, *t2*), [*t3*, *t4*), ...]]... So if you tried to make that correlation comparison between IDs 1 and 2, you would be missing that first interval. Something to think about, perhaps.

Comment: Reading your comment again, you actually might be looking for merging of the two data frames. Something like `merge(skin, room, by = 'ID')` so that you know which skin observations correspond to the proper room observations experiment...