# How to merge by time in data.table, when time resolution is different?

Tags: r, merge, data.table, time-series

Lets say we have, two time-series data.tables,  one sampled by day, another by hour:

```
dtByDay
     EURO       TIME    ... and some other columns
    <num>     <POSc>
 1:  0.95 2017-01-20
 2:  0.97 2017-01-21
 3:  0.98 2017-01-22
 ...

dtByHour
                  TIME           TEMP   ... also some other columns
                <POSc>          <num>
1: 2017-01-20 00:00:00           22.45
2: 2017-01-20 01:00:00           23.50
3: 2017-01-20 02:00:00           23.50
...
```

and we need to merge them, so that to get all columns together. What's a nice what of doing it?

Evidently `dtByDay[dtByHour]` does not produce the desired outcome (as one could have wished) - you get `NA' in "EURO" column ...

Comment: I think this is where you want `roll = TRUE` These posts may help: https://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030932/rolling-joins-data-table-in-r

Comment: You are not asking a programming question, are you? You are seeking a statistical method for merging coarser data with another dataframe.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360403/496488) helpful.

Comment: This is a purely programming question. I'm just aggregating data from different sources, so that I can started do data modeling from there. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to comments above! - The solution is as easy as just adding `roll=Inf` argument when joining:

```
dtByHour[dtByDay, roll=Inf]
```

That's exactly what I needed. It takes `dtByDay` value and use it for all hours of this day. The output (from my application) is shown below.

For other applications, you may also consider `roll="nearest"`. This will take the closest (from midnight) dtByDay value for all hours before and after midnight:

```
dtByHour[dtByDay, roll="nearest"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `roll = TRUE` might give you funny behavior if a date is present in one data frame but no the other. So I wanted to post this alternative:

Starting with your original data frames:

```
dtbyday <- data.frame( EURO = c(0.95,0.97,0.98),
                       TIME = c(ymd("2017-01-20"),ymd("2017-01-21"),ymd("2017-01-22")))
dtbyhour <- data.frame( TEMP = c(22.45,23.50,23.40),
                       TIME = c(ymd_hms("2017-01-21 00:00:00"),ymd_hms("2017-01-21 01:00:00"),ymd_hms("2017-01-21 02:00:00")))
```

I converted the `byhour$TIME` to the same format as the `byday$TIME` using `lubridate` functions

```
dtbyhour <- dtbyhour %>%
            rowwise() %>%
            mutate( TIME = ymd( paste( year(TIME), month(TIME), day(TIME), sep="-" ) ) )
dtbyhour

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   TEMP       TIME
  <dbl>     <date>
1 22.45 2017-01-20
2 23.50 2017-01-20
3 23.40 2017-01-20
```

NOTE: The date changed because of time zone issues.

Then use `dplyr::full_join` to join by `TIME`, which will keep all records, and impute values whenever possible. You'll need to aggregate `byHour` values on a particular day...I calculated the mean `TEMP` below.

```
new.dt <- full_join( dtbyday, dtbyhour, by = c("TIME") ) %>%
          group_by( TIME ) %>%
          summarize( EURO = unique( EURO ),
                     TEMP = mean( TEMP, na.rm = TRUE ) )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
        TIME  EURO     TEMP
      <date> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2017-01-20  0.95 23.11667
2 2017-01-21  0.97      NaN
3 2017-01-22  0.98      NaN
```